# Defining multiple functions in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to writing code, and I'm working through "Learn Python the Hard Way." I want to define both PersonName and Hoarder so that I get the following result:

**Fred had 45 cats.

Bill had 20 dogs.

That is a lot of animals.

Find a therapist!**

```
def PersonName(name1, name2): 
def Hoarder(number_of_cats, number_of_dogs):
    print "%r had %d cats." % (name1, number_of_cats)
    print "%r had %d dogs." % (name2, number_of_dogs)
    print "That is a lot of animals."
    print "Find a therapist!"

print
Person("Fred", "Bill")
Hoarder(45,20)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So, what's the issue?

Comment: This won't work without some kind of global variable and that wouldn't be a good idea. Could you give us a link to the exercise?

Comment: Try to comment each row, to help you understand the exact behaviour

Comment: @PaulWritesCode, Why dont you change the function arguments for `PersonName` to include number of cats and dogs as well - `PersonName(name1, name2, number_of_cats, number_of_dogs)`

Comment: @AshokaLella rolling back your edit as I don't think there's any evidence the OP meant to define a nested function here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def PersonName(name1, name2): 
    def Hoarder(number_of_cats, number_of_dogs):
        print "%r had %d cats." % (name1, number_of_cats)
        print "%r had %d dogs." % (name2, number_of_dogs)
        print "That is a lot of animals."
        print "Find a therapist!"
    Hoarder(45,20)

PersonName("Fred", "Bill")

'Fred' had 45 cats.
'Bill' had 20 dogs.
That is a lot of animals.
Find a therapist!
```

if you really want to define two function, you need write them as above. Also please pay attention the scope of function.

Comment: @Ashoka Lella, changing PersonName to include name AND number of cats/dogs was the simplest solution.

Comment: yours works as well, although I'm not sure why it worked without saying 'print' before Hoarder or PersonName.